# SQL Error 1452: Cannot add or update child

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
Create table Course(CourseID char(5),CourseDesc varchar(25),CourseType char(9),SemNo int(1),FacID char(4) default 0);
alter table Course add primary key(CourseID);
alter table Course add foreign key(FacID) references Faculty1(FacID);
```

here FacID is the foreign key which the primary key of the Faculty
when i am inserting values, i try insert this values

```
insert into Course(CouseID,CourseDesc,CourseType,SemNo,FacID) values ('EE025','Digital Logic Circuits','Theory','4','');
```

But,this produces sql error 1452 ,please resolve it .

Comment: Can you try seeing the FacID values in Faculty table and enter any value from those values for FacId instread of putting '' there?

Comment: Add something like this:

insert into Course(CouseID,CourseDesc,CourseType,SemNo,FacID) values ('EE025','Digital Logic Circuits','Theory','4','G'); where 'G' is there in FacId columns in Faculty table.

Comment: is this mysql or sql-server ?

Comment: there is no faculty id refers it, it has (null ) value

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled CourseID in your insert:

```
insert into Course(CouseID,CourseDes...
```

Should be:

```
insert into Course(CourseID,CourseDes...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that you have a row in `Faculty1` with `FacID = 0`?

```
insert into Faculty1 (FacID /* other columns */) values (0 /*, other values*/ );
insert into Course(CourseID,CourseDesc,CourseType,SemNo,FacID) values ('EE025','Digital Logic Circuits','Theory',4,0);
```

---

If you want to insert a blank value (`''`) then you need to have an empty string value in `Faculty1.FacID`. Otherwise you could properly indicate a `'0'`.

```
create table Faculty1(
    FacID char(4) not null primary key
);
insert into faculty1 values (0);

create table Course(
    CourseID char(5) not null
  , CourseDesc varchar(25)
  , CourseType char(9)
  , SemNo int
  , FacID char(4) not null default 0 
    /* specify not null to use default when value not inserted */
); 
alter table Course add primary key(CourseID);
alter table Course add foreign key(FacID) references Faculty1(FacID);

/* inserting `''` instead of `0` for FacId results in an error */
begin try;
insert into Course(CourseID,CourseDesc,CourseType,SemNo,FacID) values 
('EE025','Digital Logic Circuits','Theory','4','');
end try
begin catch
select error_message();
end catch;

/* inserting `0` for FacId = no error*/
insert into Course(CourseID,CourseDesc,CourseType,SemNo,FacID) values 
  ('EE025','Digital Logic Circuits','Theory',4,'0');
select * from Course;

/* inserting without specifying FacId uses default*/
insert into Course(CourseID,CourseDesc,CourseType,SemNo) values 
  ('EE026','Digital Logic Circuits','Theory',4);
select * from Course;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZYGWRX20984

Comment: @rajesh Updated my answer with an example and demo to illustrate.